# Why does view_layer.update seemingly fail for my armature?

Tags: python, scripting, armature, bones, viewlayers

I'm writing an export script for an armature (using Blender 3.0.0). In this script, I'm attempting to clear bone roll, then force local bone matrices (`bone.matrix_local`) to be recomputed before writing to a file, as follows:

```py
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')

# I could also use bpy.ops.armature.roll_clear()
for editBone in armature.edit_bones:
    editBone.roll = 0

# I've tried this script with and without the following line (setting the armature's node to be active).
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = node
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```

This seemingly has no effect, as I've confirmed that exported local bone matrices include roll (rather than zeroing roll first). What am I missing? **How can I force the export script to recompute bone matrices immediately?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you need to exit edit mode for changes to be applied. It works the same way for meshes actually. For example

```
# Make sure the armature is the thing you're editing
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = arma_ob

# Switch to edit mode
if bpy.context.mode != 'EDIT':
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

# Clear all rolls
for editBone in arma_ob.data.edit_bones:
    editBone.roll = 0

# Exit edit mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

# Access the new bone.matrix_local here
```